# Is the key created by RegCreateKeyEx() open?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

The Windows documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx states that the `RegCreateKeyEx()` function creates or opens the specified key, depending on whether the key already exists.

However, I'm not sure whether the key saved into `phkResult` is open when the key is created. How do I check this? I cannot read it directly from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

"If the key is not one of the predefined registry keys, call the **RegCloseKey** function after you have finished using the handle."

If they ask you to call close, it means that it is open.

Regards

Comment: Thank you, Sven Nilsson. That's a bit cryptic way of saying that the key is opened! :-)